# Golang JSON Encoder and nginx proxy buffering

Tags: json, nginx, go

I am working on a web app backend in golang that has a JSON api, it resides behind nginx 1.8.0.

Nginx Config:

```
server {

  listen      80;
  server_name someserver.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host                   $http_host;
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;

    # The go server handles the chunking, so with proxy_buffering on it messes up the response
    proxy_buffering  off;
  }
}
```

I handle routes like:

```
router.GET("/api/cases", checkAuth(api.GetAllCases))
```

My checkAuth middleware looks like:

```
func checkAuth(h httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    url := strings.Split(r.URL.String(), "/")
    if notAuthenticatedCode {
      http.Error(w, "", http.StatusUnauthorized)
    } else {
      if url[1] == "api" {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
      } else {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
      }
      h(w, r, ps)
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, a JSON endpoint that looks like:

```
func (api API) GetAllCases(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
  // It used to write the json in a different manner, I think this
  // is where I started receiving the error when I changed to this
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Cases)
}
```

At some point while working on this I began receiving an error about incomplete chunked encoding. I'm not 100% sure what I changed when I began receiving this error. While investigating this issue I discovered that apparently the go server is handling response chunking, then nginx would also try to handle it causing issues. I added "proxy_buffering off" into the location block of the nginx config and it corrected this issue.

My question: Am I missing out on anything with this set up versus allowing nginx to handle the buffering and disabling it in Go? If I am, how would I disable the chunking in the go server?

It seems to me that nginx should be handling the chunking/compressing/etc and golang shouldn't, but may be this is a naive assumption. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using nginx here at all?

Comment: I don't have a real good answer for that. This is the setup when I came onto the project. I think eventually it is intended to be load balanced and have several upstream servers.

Comment: Oh, also nginx handles the ssl termination in production environment.

Comment: Disabling chunked encoding in go would be inconvenient. You either need to figure out why your nginx is truncating responses (probably permission issue for creating temp files), or turn `proxy_buffering` off, as you have. There's nothing wrong with having Go do the encoding.

Comment: Thanks, that has settled my doubts. If you want to leave it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If the response body is smaller than [default buffer size (4k)](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffer_size), try setting `proxy_buffer_size` to reduce the buffer size.